# how can we use environment variables properly with env.config.js file in react.js(i got undefined after reload)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

When I'm running project with `npm run start` it's working fine after reloading my env.config.js giving variables undefined
I have got a problem with env-config.js file. I implemented like this below

**App.js file**

```
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const Query = window._env_.REACT_APP_QUERY;
  console.log(Query);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>hello world</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is **env-config.js file**

```
window._env_ = {
  REACT_APP_GRANT: "grate",
  REACT_APP_CLIENT: "simple",
};
```

finally **scripts in package-json file**

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "chmod +x .\\env.sh  && cp env-config.js .\\public/ && .\\env.sh && react-scripts start",
    "dev": "chmod +x ./env.sh && ./env.sh && cp env-config.js ./public/ && react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build": "react-scripts build"
  },
```

I don't know about this file it was mentioned in scripts then I copied it here
**env.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Recreate config file
rm -rf ./env-config.js
touch ./env-config.js

# Add assignment 
echo "window._env_ = {" >> ./env-config.js

# Read each line in .env file
# Each line represents key=value pairs
while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
do
  # Split env variables by character `=`
  if printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep -q -e '='; then
    # tollerate = surrounded by blanks: ' = ' 
    varname=$(printf '%s\n' "$line" | sed -E 's/^([a-zA-Z_-]+) *= *(.*)$/\1/')
    varvalue=$(printf '%s\n' "$line" | sed -E 's/^([a-zA-Z_-]+) *= *(.*)$/\2/')
  fi

  # Read value of current variable if exists as Environment variable
  value=$(printf '%s\n' "${!varname}")
  # Otherwise use value from .env file
  [[ -z $value ]] && value=${varvalue}
  
  # Append configuration property to JS file
  echo "  $varname: \"$value\"," >> ./env-config.js
done < .env.local

echo "}" >> ./env-config.js
```

I'm running my project with git bash terminal with `npm run start` command

1. I don't want to use .env file for some varables because I'm unable to overide with docker build command
2. how can we get env-config.js variables without getting undefined after reload the project.

I'm not sure about `env.sh file` any more I couldn't understand what they coded earlier in that even don't know use of it

Answer (score -1):

The comments in the script tell you what it is doing. It removes the `env-config.js` file, recreates it with the variables in `.env` file in the `window._env_` variable. So, if you don't have a `.env` file, there will be no variables added to the `window._env_` variable.

I suggest you remove the `env.sh` and use `dotenv` npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

1. Install `dotenv`

```bash
npm i dotenv
```

2. Create `.env` file with the variables you want

```bash
REACT_APP_GRANT=grate
REACT_APP_CLIENT=simple
```

3. Use `dotenv` inside `env-config.js` file

```js
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

// dotenv reads the .env file and adds the variables in
// there to process.env
dotenv.config()

window._env_ = {
  REACT_APP_GRANT: process.env.REACT_APP_GRANT,
  REACT_APP_CLIENT: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT,
};
```

Success!

If you set a variable like this: `REACT_APP_GRANT=newgrant npm run start`, `dotenv`, by default, will not overwrite `newgrant` for the one in `.env`. I believe the same will work when setting the variable in docker command line if you use `docker run --env REACT_APP_GRANT=newgrant myapp`

EDIT:

Apparently, reactjs already uses `dotenv`, so you might not need to install it. All you need to do is create the `.env` file and add the `REACT_APP_` prefix to your variable names, like you are already doing. Then you can access them via `process.env.REACT_APP_MY_VAR`, as I did in my example.

Read more at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/